# Serialization error with firebase on Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, serialization

I'm trying to run a transaction with realtime database to change an object, with the following code :

```
void tryBeHost()
{
    string path = "weeks/" + week + "/games/" + gameId + "/gameInfo";
    _dbRef.Child(path).RunTransaction(mutableData =>
    {
        GameInfo gameInfo = mutableData.Value as GameInfo;

        if (gameInfo == null)
        {
            gameInfo = new GameInfo();
        }
        else if (gameInfo.host != null && gameInfo.host != myId)
        {
            return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
        }
        gameInfo.host = myId;
        mutableData.Value = gameInfo;
        return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);

    });
}
```

so I'm getting this weird error :

**Exception in transaction delegate, aborting transaction
Firebase.Database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse object Serializables.GameInfo ---> System.ArgumentException: Invalid type Serializables.GameInfo for conversion to Variant
at Firebase.Variant.FromObject (System.Object o) [0x001df] in Z:\tmp\tmp.EaS8iXpRBh\firebase\app\client\unity\proxy\Variant.cs:117
at Firebase.Database.Internal.Utilities.MakeVariant (System.Object value) [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.sZ8vrpcx53\firebase\database\client\unity\proxy\Utilities.cs:25
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Firebase.Database.Internal.Utilities.MakeVariant (System.Object value) [0x0000d] in Z:\tmp\tmp.sZ8vrpcx53\firebase\database\client\unity\proxy\Utilities.cs:27
at Firebase.Database.MutableData.set_Value (System.Object value) [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.sZ8vrpcx53\firebase\database\client\unity\proxy\MutableData.cs:136
at InternetShit.b__10_0 (Firebase.Database.MutableData mutableData) [0x00045] in /Users/sandukhan/Unity/projects/Ronda/Assets/Scripts/InternetShit.cs:73
at Firebase.Database.Internal.InternalTransactionHandler.DoTransaction (System.Int32 callbackId, System.IntPtr mutableData) [0x00022] in
Z:\tmp\tmp.sZ8vrpcx53\firebase\database\client\unity\proxy\InternalTransactionHandler.cs:49
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseLogger:LogMessage(PlatformLogLevel, String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.BbQyA8B710/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseLogger.cs:92)
Firebase.LogUtil:LogMessage(LogLevel, String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.EaS8iXpRBh/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/LogUtil.cs:68)
Firebase.Database.Internal.InternalTransactionHandler:DoTransaction(Int32, IntPtr) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.sZ8vrpcx53/firebase/database/client/unity/proxy/InternalTransactionHandler.cs:51)
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.EaS8iXpRBh/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/AppUtil.cs:32)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseAppUtils:PollCallbacks() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.EaS8iXpRBh/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseAppUtils.cs:33)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.BbQyA8B710/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseHandler.cs:205)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.BbQyA8B710/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseMonoBehaviour.cs:45)**

my GameInfo Class is the following :

```
using System;
using Serializables;

namespace Serializables
{
    [Serializable]
    public class GameInfo
    {

        public string gameId;
        public string host;
        public string[] playersIds;
        public string[] playersPics;
        public string[] playersNames;
    }
}
```

if anyone has an idea to solve this I will be grateful

Comment: What is the value  of your mutableData.Value   in debug ?

Comment: @DespeiL it's `null`

Comment: So first of all you should figure out why do you have null.  I can't  pars null to some object =0

Comment: but I'm creating new GameInfo object if it's `null`, and I think null is a parsable value for firebase (e.i when you ask firebase to write null in field it means : delete it)

Comment: You can't  do this : `mutableData.Value as GameInfo`   if  `mutableData.Value`  is null.
Before parsing `mutableData.Value`  to GameInfo  check if mutableData.Value is not null.
If it isn't  parse  else  create new object of GameInfo

Comment: @DespeiL I tried what you suggested but it doesn't change anything :

Comment: `_dbRef.Child(path).RunTransaction(mutableData =>
        {
            GameInfo gameInfo = new GameInfo();
            print("value is => " + mutableData.Value);
            if (gameInfo.host != null && gameInfo.host != myId)
            {
                gameInfo = mutableData.Value as GameInfo;
                return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
            }
            gameInfo.host = myId;
            mutableData.Value = gameInfo;
            return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
        });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you figured out the basics: You can only submit `bool`, `string`, `long`, `double`,  `IDictionary`, and `List<Object>` to `Value`.

There's some interesting notes that I'd like to layer on top of this though! I like to use [Unity's `JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) in conjunction with [`SetRawJsonValueAsync`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/database-reference#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_database_reference_1adeb74c29f9619d905e04af20b4aa1e52) and [`GetRawJsonValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_data_snapshot_1aeac5f8a0bcdf5bc3761a13f9f7081570) from [`GetValueAsync`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/query#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_query_1a42a42204ed15f65fa54e8e21c6c92474). Your code will look a bit like this:

```
async void SendGameInfo(string path, GameInfo info) {
    try {
        await _database
            .GetReference(path)
            .SetRawJsonValueAsync(JsonUtility.ToJson(info));
        Debug.Log($"Successfully wrote {info}");
    } catch (AggregateException e) {
        Debug.LogWarning($"Failed with {e}");
    }
}
```

```
async Task<GameInfo> ReadGameInfo(string path) {
    try {
        var dataSnapshot = await _database
            .GetReference(path)
            .GetValueAsync();
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<GameInfo>(info);
    } catch (AggregateException e) {
        Debug.LogWarning($"Failed with {e}");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, if you can, having spent time digging through the library I like to consider `IDictionary<string, object>` the "basic primitive" of Realtime Database. This will be used as an intermediary format when you set RawJson if you step through the disassembly. Also, since `Transactions` don't provide access to raw json, this will give you a more uniform interface to RTDB (unless your data looks like an array, then your primitive is `List<object>` - "looks like" meaning that your keys are numbers and the range of numbers RTDB is aware of is about half full).

Of course, the team actively monitors the [quickstart github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues) page and you can use the new "feature request" template to request a change to any of this if it will help .

Comment: But, as OP also wanted, can we set mutableData via these helpers ? I am also looking for a way to set mutableData inside a transaction, where the value contains types that are not directly supported (e.g. `string[]`). Currently I am using `Dictionary<string, object>` approach. I wish there's a way to set a rawJson to mutableData.Value.

Answer (score 1):

I think RTFM always works, I found out that there are specific types that are accepted for mutableData.Value : bool, string, long, double, IDictionary and List{Object} where Object is one of previously listed types. So I got this error because my class GameInfo is not accepted and I have to convert my object to an IDictionary.
source : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/mutable-data#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_mutable_data_1a4833f23246b3079078332d57c5649254